# Почему не работает mysqli_query() и mysqli_fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Источник https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_5RGo38cdc&list=LLHgPabR2InepdgXHIaptdsQ&index=5&t=962s 
Код выглядит так,

```
    <?php
     $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','...','...','...');
    if (!$mysqli){
        die("Connaction failed" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    function get_posts() {
        global $musqli;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
   "line6" $result = mysqli_query($musqli, $sql);
   "line7" $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $posts;
    }

                    <pre><?php var_dump($posts) ?></pre>
                <?php 

                $posts = get_posts ();

                 ?>

        "line 78"        <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>

                 ДИВ В КОТОРОМ ПОДСТАВЛЕНЫ ПАРАМЕТРЫ

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ошибка Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\Project2\Index.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\Project2\Index.php on line 7

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\Project2\Index.php on line 78

Comment: `$mysqli` превращается в `$musqli`, так и задумано?

Comment: Да, я ошибся, исправил, работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит init базы данных в "ООП", а переменные "процедурным".

В ООП переменная имеет вид объекта: `$mysqli->query();`

В процедурном: `mysqli_query($link, $query);`, где, к примеру, `$link = mysqli_connect();`

Будет полезно: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не совсем понял

Comment: @ПетяСальбич у тебя инит базы данных объектом, измени или переменные на вид объекта, т.к у тебя в процедурном, или просто измени db в $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', ..); И у тебя ошибка в 9 строке, переменная $musqli с опечаткой

Comment: ХАХАХА оо лорд. Опечатка дело страшное, спасибо большое, заработало ))